# Posting php over to html form wraped up in my own code

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Hello i have what i need in side

```
$v->id
```

But i need to get it from this page over to testing.php
here is my code

```
echo '

                                <div class="auction_box" style="height:150px">

                                <form name="myform" action="http://mysite.net/new_rpg/testing.php?' .$v->id. '" method="POST">
                                <p> </p>
                                <p> </p>
                                <p> </p>

                                        <img src="http://pokemontoxic.net/new_rpg/'.$battle_get['pic'].'" height="96px" width="96px"/><br/>


                                    Name:<br/>' .$v->pokemon. '<br/>
                                    Level:' .$v->level. '<br/>
                                    Exp:' .$v->exp. '<br/>
                                    Slot you want to put your pokemon in


<select name="mydropdown">

<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
</select>



<select name="hfghfhg">

< option value="' .$v->id. '" input type="hidden"> Please leave</option>

</select>
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

                                </form>
                                </div>';
                            }
                        }
```

I am submitting the form and getting the result from mydropdown  which i want but am not getting the result from    $v->id  how would i make a hidden field with    $v->id  in side ? so when the form is submitted it will be posted onto testing and i could do i post to get it on testing ?? Has you can see i have tryied to make a drop down which would hold the variable and then post it over to the other page and make it hidden but it ent hidden .....

```
   <select name="hfghfhg">

    < option value="' .$v->id. '" input type="hidden"> Please leave</option>

    </select>
```

Comment: please format your code so that it's readable. Don't just copy-paste the code in.

Comment: @user967149: if you don't put effort in making your code easily readable (properly indenting if for example), don't expect people to make an effort at trying to fix your issues. The comment you just posted is misguided, I'm pretty sure Johan knows how to read PHP given his profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a field to the form like this:

`'<input type="hidden" name="myName" value="' . $v->id . '" />'`

Then set myName to whatever you want your value to be on the server, and access $v->id by using `$_POST['myName']` on your target page.

Answer (score 1):

Use hidden text field which it's value is $v->id